# Always show statusbar and soft keys

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How do I configure my ionic app to always show the statusbar at the top and the softkeys on the bottom on Android?

I've tried adding this to the config.xml but it didn't help.

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="false"/>
```

Basically, I'm trying to solve the problem shown here by always rendering the status bar and soft keys and having the app operate in-between:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/soft-keys-in-android-obscure-the-bottom-of-ion-content/41128/2

Ionic version 1.3.1       Angular version 1.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I was using Intel XDK to run the app on my phone - it runs in fullscreen mode while using Ionic View or an Android emulator does not.